# Apple Appstore Search Tab API

Tags: ios, search, app-store

I would like to ask if you know where to find API for the App Store search tab. I mean that tab, where I can put the specific keyword and the API, will show me auto suggestions for this word.

Comment: Sorry, your question isn't very clear as-written; what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! When you put a word in search tab in the app store under the word there will be suggestions for example with word "fitness" there will be suggestions as "home fitness" "fitness recipes" etc. And I want to get those suggestions from the app store for every word :)

Answer (score 0):

Information about the **App Store Search API** can be found at:

[**iTunes Search API Documentation**](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/)

> The Search API allows you to place search fields in your website to
>   search for content within the iTunes Store, App Store, iBooks Store
>   and Mac App Store. You can search for a variety of content; including
>   apps, iBooks, movies, podcasts, music, music videos, audiobooks, and
>   TV shows.

---

Look up example for Yelp by app ID:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=284910350
```

Search example for an app titled “Yelp” in the US App Store:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=yelp&country=us&entity=software
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! When you put a word in search tab in the app store under the word there will be suggestions for example with word "fitness" there will be suggestions as "home fitness" "fitness recipes" etc. And I want to get those suggestions from the app store for every word :)